# Moving a User Story or Bug from one backlog to another

Tags: azure-devops

I have a user story (and a bug) in one backlog and I want to move it to another. Backlogs are associated with teams ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=azure-devops)), so I believe this amounts to moving a user story from one team to another in the same project.

Note that this is different from how one would move a task from one user story to another (which is achieved by changing the parent) and it is different from moving a work item between projects. I want to move work items between two teams (and thus two backlogs) on the same ADO project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each team has an associated area (or areas). You can find this area on the team setting page: [Configure team areas and iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-teams?view=azure-devops#configure-team-areas-and-iterations).

To move any work item from one backlog to another on the same team project, just change the Area Path of a work item to the corresponding team area path: [Move work items under teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#move-work-items-under-teams)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shamarai. I had tried the area path. It made it disappear from the source board but not appear on the target board. That seems to be because the bug/ or user story had its state set to 'active', if I set it back to 'new' it works. I do not understand why that would matter but at least I can make it work.